# Rails json response. Int converting to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a problem, with responding data in json.
Here is a code:

```
@data  [
            actions_by_type.each do |action|
              [ action[:date].to_i, action[:activity] ]
            end 
        ]
respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @data }
    end
```

But responde is:

```
...{"date":"2013-04-29T20:20:00Z","activity":"87"}...
```

Why rails convert my int time, to string datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.map` instead of `.each`.

```
@data = actions_by_type.map do |action|
            [ action[:date].to_i, action[:activity] ]
        end 

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @data }
end
```

With `.each` the result of `@data` will be the `actions_by_type` instead of the new array.

Answer (score 2):

`x.each` returns `x` so this:

```
x = actions_by_type.each do |action|
  [ action[:date].to_i, action[:activity] ]
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = actions_by_type
```

You want to use `map` instead of `each`:

```
@data = actions_by_type.map do |action|
  [ action[:date].to_i, action[:activity] ]
end
```